# Handle AlamoFire 304 result in the response block

Tags: alamofire

I am using AlamoFire 3 and have my API server cache policy headers setup correctly.

The caching is working via AlamoFire, which is great!

The issue I am having is that I would like to know if the response is a 304 or not. In the case of the 304, the client doesn't need to do any database modifications, which is what I would like to do.

At the moment the response callback thinks that it received new data, which makes the client do unnecessary database updates.

**EDIT**

I ended up saving the ETAG from the response for the request, then comparing the saved ETAG with the response's. If they match then I just return out.

Not the most elegant, but works.

Comment: You should put your edit in as an answer. I had the same question and your edit guided me to the same solution. Post that as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.